# Insert multiple records using insert statement in SQL Server database in an efficient way

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, bulkinsert

I have to insert about million records into database using insert statement. The records I have them stored as `.sql` files, then I split them into several files and start execute them via SQL Server Management Studio.

It takes many hours to do so and I searched on line to find a better way to do, but I can't find one. I use SQL Server 2014 Developer edition.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the [.sql File] has a bunch of insert statements written and you are execution one by one?

The only way I could think of is open that file only copying the insert Value into a .csv file, ofcourse make a proper.csv file with all the columns and comma separating ...., and then in SQL use -> Task ->Import Data and load it into a table,

Or open the file in xml and replace all the techical words/characters like 'Insert, values, () ..' with blank spaces and then convert the file to .csv

Again assuming its all for the same table,

Comment: I can't do this approach as the statements I use are conditionals meaning it has Select from another table and insert to another table

Comment: Looking into the Execution plan, maybe you are missing some index or the table you are inserting into has too many indexes, that would cause a slowdown.

Answer (score 1):

You should definetely try:

[Bulk Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql)

Probably you'll need to prepare comma separeted file, like csv.
Otherwise you'll need an OOP approach.

Comment: The link is italian?

Comment: I'm not sure this approach will apply for my situation as I do select from one table and insert to another.

Comment: You said that u have all inserts in .sql files. If you don't want to use OOP language, turn those inserts in comma separated csv then use BULK INSERT. Other than that you can only execute statement by statement.

Comment: As the Ansert statmments validated with (if not exists (Select from...) begin insert to)) I believe the only option I have is to insert them statement by statment. I'm not sure if it is possible to use a stored procedure to validate in case of BULK INSERT approch